# why android:layout_gravity="right" not working here in android xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, gravity, layout-gravity

my xml code for list view's row is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_image"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/app_icon_17"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_delete_new"
            android:focusable="false" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want the last button with id btn_delete to stay right aligned. And its showing as I wanted in "graphical layout" while designing. But when I run it, on emulator it's not working.

See the output :

[image]

So why the delete button not getting right aligned?

Comment: I think If you use `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout` then both are better then `LinearLayout` and you will get what you want.. I preferred `RelativeLayout` as like this type of List Row design..

Comment: Add layout_gravity for your button and try out!

Comment: because horizontal linear layout ignores layout_gravity right, left and horizontal center. It care only about vertical gravity.

Comment: @njzk2 : an obvious but very easy to miss thing that you mentioned. Solved my problem. Thanks !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this, using relative layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_delete_new"
            android:focusable="false" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rl_btn" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_image"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/app_icon_17"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

You seem to have misunderstood layouts, those embedded `LinearLayouts` aren't needed. Use a `RelativeLayout`, e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_time"
        android:background="@drawable/app_icon_17"
        android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_delete_new"
        android:focusable="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what can I read to understand them? And understand weights aswell

Answer (score 1):

As we can see that you have assign weight to your row layout.

If you assign weight your **parent layout** you just need to set accordingly height or with `0dp`.
  In your case `android:layout_width="0dp"`

but when you have child layout of that weighted layout then you must give that layouts property as `fill_parent` i.e: button's  `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`

**So if you don't want to change your parent layout and want to work with existing code you can try below code.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon"
            android:focusable="false" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_delete_new"
            android:focusable="false" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

to

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_delete_new"
            android:focusable="false" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

You were applying `android:layout_gravity="right"` to layout. Instead, you should apply it to a button inside layout. And I don't think you need weight 2 for that layout. But you can add it if its required for you. Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry .I applied this answer .But there is no response

Answer (score -3):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_delete_new"
        android:focusable="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What does this answer represent?

Comment: Code with no explanation is rarely helpful.